# How to make a propertysheetpage be a selection provider?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I've got a contributed command and a handler for it. The handler's execute event has to get the value for the property actually selected in the properties view and act on it, or to be disabled if no property selected.

I've tried:

1) Set the selection provider to something which provides selection from the property view. Something in this case is just PropertySheetViewer for my PropertySheetPage, but i can't set it as the selection provider because the PropertySheetPage's viewer is private and has no getter.

2) Overriding PropertySheetPage's createControl method: This method creates a Tree control for the PropertySheetViewer. A selection listener can be installed for that tree control, so maybe i can make my command handler implement SelectionListener... The solution would be somethin like:

In my editor:

```
public Object getAdapter(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class type) {
        if (type == IPropertySheetPage.class) {
            PropertySheetPage page = new PropertySheetPage() {
                @Override
                public void createControl(Composite parent) {
                    super.createControl(parent);

                                    IHandler handler = someWayToGetMyCmdHandler();
                    ((org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree) getControl())
                            .addSelectionListener(handler);
                }

            };
            IPropertySheetEntry entry = new UndoablePropertySheetEntry(
                    getCommandStack());
            page.setRootEntry(entry);
            return page;
        }

    return super.getAdapter(type);
}
```

And my command handler implementing SelectionListener as i said... The problem with this approach is that i can't find a way to get a reference to my contributed command handler (someWayToGetMyCmdHandler() above).

Has anybody got any clue on this, or any other possible approach to the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `handleEntrySelection(ISelection selection)` method in [`PropertySheetPage`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/views/properties/PropertySheetPage.html) that you could override to be notified about selection changes in the viewer (although `PropertySheetPage` is `@noextend`).

The second part (updating the handler) is a bit more tricky than it would normally be. Commands/handlers get updated automatically when workbench selection changes (you just need to implement `setEnabled(Object evaluationContext)` [`AbstractHandler`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/commands/AbstractHandler.html)). But since `PropertySheetPage` is designed to change its input on global selection change, then you have to find some custom way to notify/update your handler.

As I understand, it is currently not possible to extend the platform command event handling mechanism with custom variables, so you just need to directly look up your handler using [`IHandlerService`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/handlers/IHandlerService.html) of the workbench.

Comment: I've added a private "selection" property in my command handler and a getter/setter for it as a way to customly notify/update the handler as you purposed. I think it would be interesting to update the answer with info about how to look up the handler with IHandlerService, may i edit the answer to add this info?